# Getting values from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have the following Json

```
{
    "title": "my title",
    "children":
    [
        {
            "id":1,
            "value1": 1
            "value2": 2
        },
        {
            "id":1,
            "value1": 1
            "value2": 2
        },
    ]
}
```

How can in Angular, iterate trough the values, and get only value1 + value2?

Comment: Not really an angular question, just a JSON parsing one. Where are you having difficulties?

Comment: What's the specific issue?

Comment: `json.children.map(function(child) { return [child.value1,child.value2]; })`

Comment: Something like, `ng-repeat = 'child in Obj.children'` ?

Comment: i want to iterate through the json, getting only the value1 and value2 values, and printing them out? I always know the name of the keys (value1 and value2), if that makes it easier

Comment: use `ng-repeat`. Any beginning tutorial will show you how to do that. Question is far too vague. Be more specific and you should be showing what you tried to resolve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just extract value1 and value2 from children array in your controller:

```
$scope.items = obj.children.map(function(r){ return {value1: r.value1, value2: r.value2 };
```

and then loop through items in your views

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items"> 
    {{item.value1}} {{item.value2}}
</div>
```

Comment: doubt that OP needs the mapping and it is probably misleading that it is necessry